# Prove $\sum x^n (1-{2x \over \pi})^n \tan^{2n} x$ converges uniformly.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\forall \alpha:0<\alpha<{\pi \over 2}$.

Prove:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n \left(1-{2x \over \pi}\right)^n \tan^{2n} x$$ converges uniformly in $[0,\alpha]$.

It's easy to get $$S_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n x^k \left(1-{2x \over \pi}\right)^k \tan^{2k} x={x\left(1-{2x \over \pi} \right)\tan^2 x\left[1- x^n \left(1-{2x \over \pi}\right)^n \tan^{2n} x\right] \over 1-x\left(1-{2x \over \pi}\right)\tan^2 x}$$.

But I can't figure out $S(x)$.

Comment: Replacing or blanking out the question leaves the answer without context. Do not do this.

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii I am trying to flag the question.Sorry,I won't do it again.

Comment: You don't need to flag or do anything about it. Just leave it in a form such that it makes sense together with the answer

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii OK,thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is not true. The function
$$
f(x)=x\Bigl(1-\frac{2\,x}{\pi}\Bigr)\tan^2 x
$$
is increasing. Let $\beta\approx1.0346$ be the solution of $f(x)=1$. The series does not converge for $x\ge\beta$. It converges uniformly on $[0,\gamma]$ if $0\le\gamma<\beta$.

Comment: Sorry,I made a mistake.I have corrected it.How to prove it now?

Comment: I suggest that you revert to the original question and ask a new one with the correct statement. Now my answer is nonsense!

Comment: I'm sorry about that.I'll ask a new question.